# 自然言語処理のデータセットについて

Tags: 機械学習, 自然言語処理

以下のように，単語と文にマルチラベルが付与されているデータセットを探しています．

< text > 
it be very overpriced and not very tasty
< wrd-label >
non non non non [food,price] non non non [food]
< stc-label >
[food, price]

心当たりがあれば教えてください．よろしくお願します．